# Android: Calculate acceleration of the car when phone is disoriented

Tags: android

How do I measure the acceleration values during the following scenario:
Carrying the phone in the car, phone could be in my pocket or some where else, not perfectly oriented. My question is how to measure linear and angular acceleration of the car.

Answer (score 1):

You will get no angular acceleration  witout gyroscopes ( not every phone is equiped with them ) For lienear acceleration you are invited to  use:

https://github.com/ko5tik/accmeter

And here is complete example:

https://github.com/ko5tik/accanalyser

In case you do not have gyroscopes, you may try to get angular  acceleration out of vector direction changes and magnetic sensor - but precision will  be suboptimal.